# How to preload text into text area in v-for loop(vue)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am struggling on something that I thought would first be easy to solve.

Imagine a page loading with multiple text areas as:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in articles" class="bg-white shadow-lg sm:rounded-lg gap-3 mt-2" :key="index">
  <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
  <textarea v-model="form5.fullArticle" :value="item.paragraph"  id="topicDescription" :rows="5" cols="80">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

When the `v-for` loop runs, I am getting a lot of `item.paragraph` and `item.title` data and would like to save them to an array.

**Problem 1:**
I cannot work out how to preload `{{item.paragraph}}` into a text area. It looks like :value="" is not accepted. and I also tried this `<textarea>{{item.paragraph}}</textarea>` but no luck (I did not expect this behavior).

**Problem 2:**
How can I save in my `v-for` the `{item.title}}` and `{{item.paragraph}}` into a new array (but group them together).

Any idea please?

Thanks!

Comment: you'd need to do that in maybe a  `computed` property - does "a lot of" mean all? or just some of them based on some condition? "save them to an array" for what purpose? they are in an array already anyway, `articles`

Comment: also ... multiple textarea's using the same `v-model="form5.fullArticle"` looks all kinds of whacky

Comment: @bravo, the reason I need to re-add them to a new array is that the data will be editable in each of the looped text areas. ie: I get 5 titles and 5 paragraphs, I edit 4 of them, I need to resend the new data to MySQL. I will try with a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use just v-model (it is the shortcut of [`:value="text"`
`@input="event => text = event.target.value"`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html)) :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [{id: 1, title: "AAA", paragraph: "aaa"}, {id: 2, title: "BBB", paragraph: "bbb"},{id: 3, title: "CCC", paragraph: "ccc"}],
      newArray: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveArt(item) {
      const found = this.newArray.find(a => a.id === item.id)
      if (!found) this.newArray.push(item)
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in articles" class="bg-white shadow-lg sm:rounded-lg gap-3 mt-2" :key="index">
    <h5>{{item.title}}</h5>
    <textarea v-model="item.paragraph"  id="topicDescription" :rows="3" cols="30">
    </textarea>
    <button @click="saveArt(item)">Add</button>
  </div>
  <p>new array</p>
  {{ newArray }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for the delay in replying to you, if the v-model is item.paragraph and the title is item.title, how would you then save both to a new array?

Comment: @Benny hey mate, please take a look at my answer again, I updated it